# How to Fix Paypal Verified Address with OpenCart?

Tags: paypal, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

We are having some issues with the PayPal Verified address. It does not seem to import from OpenCart. Payments are received by PayPal, but PayPal does not receive an address from the customer, and therefore the order is not covered by the protection program. This is a major issue due to potential disputed charges. How can we ensure that the address is correctly imported into paypal?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass a variable noshipping=2 if it is [Express Checkout Integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/), then PayPal will grab the address from the buyer profile and it will show inside the transaction details. If you are using [WPS integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/), please pass the variable no_shipping=2 in the button code from your website.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm very new at this kind of thing, can you please give me a bit more details about how to "pass the variable" in the button? I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Please refer the below HTML button code:
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="test@test.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">