# Fix Paypal Verified Address with OpenCart 3.0.2.0

Tags: paypal, opencart

Payments are received by PayPal, but PayPal does not receive an address from the customer, and therefore the order is not covered by the protection program.

I pass a variable noshipping=2  and addroverride=0, but still didn't work, the path is /catalog/view/theme/default/template/extension/payment/pp_standard.twig. I use theme journal3

Are there anything else wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Edit：
"still doesn't work" means Payments are received by PayPal, but PayPal does not receive an verified address from the customer after i pass the variable noshipping=2.

**Before this, most of order "PayPal does not receive an verified address from the customer", just a part of order is normal.**

Yesterday i found error log "PP_STANDARD :: IPN RESPONSE: VERIFIED
PP_STANDARD :: RECEIVER EMAIL MISMATCH! A@A.com", then i change paypal email B@A.com to A@A.com, B@A.com is the email that i fill in extension >paypal payments standard, email B@A.com and A@A.com are belong to same paypal account. 
Today i got a order and PayPal received  an verified address, but i am not sure it's solved or not.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4qhW.png)

Comment: Please provide more information about the situation and what "still doesn't work" means, exactly. In the classic APIs, noshipping=2 will require that a shipping address be part of the transaction

Comment: "still doesn't work" means PayPal does not receive an address from the customer after i pass the variable noshipping=2.

Comment: And what does "PayPal does not receive an verified address from the customer" mean, exactly? Are you sending an address at payment creation time that you want to force as part of the transaction?

Comment: Please refer this → https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738842/how-to-fix-paypal-verified-address-with-opencart

Problem solved. First i pass the variable noshipping=2, then change the paypal email address according to error log mentioned.
Thanks!